# tests running really slow on IE 8 and IE 9 using selenium 2.29 and IEDriverServer.exe

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am running scripts using selenium version 2.29 and IEDriverServer.exe 64 on Internet explorer 8 and 9 both of them are 64 bit. 
When I run these tests on firefox it takes around 2 min but in IE its takes around 20-40 min and they dont run at all sometime just get stuck. We use a windows server 2008 r2 and java jdk jdk1.7.0_11 64 bit version.
We by pass the initial certificates using

```
selenium.getWebDriver().navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Is there is way to make these tests faster. I even close the instance of IEDriverServer.exe everytime I close the browser.

Is there is a way to make my tests faster?

Comment: I've had similar problems on windows 2008 r2 + IE 9.  Make sure you're not spawning multiple instances of IE at the same time.  That doesn't work properly.  Also check to see if protected mode is set the same on all security modes (internet, trusted, etc).  If you can stop the hangs, it will run much faster. I also found that mixed mode was a reason mine would hang.  Fixing CSS to load images via HTTPS helped.

Comment: @Lucas: I too have the problem and i did all the things which you mentioned above. Nothing sounds good.

Comment: What happens when you yes the 32-bit version of the IEDriverServer.exe?

Answer (score 0):

After hearing what is happening and outside of the spawning multiple instances (Thanks Lucas) the other thing that comes to mind as a culprit is what kind of locators you are using.  Using Xpath slows IE way down, though the time difference is a bit extreme for that to be the only problem.

If you are using xpath, try switching to id or name locators.  If your testing is anything like mine though, those aren't always available.  If that is the case, CSS works better(faster) in IE instead of xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use 32 bit Version of IE driver and Run the test suite. it will work for Sure